# ForegroundService notification not working

Tags: javascript, expo, geolocation

SDK Version: 48
Platforms: Android

I have an app that is supposed to record the location even when the app is running in the background. However, after a certain time, the location is always sent at longer intervals.
To prevent this, the foreground service should be activated. However, this does not show any notification.

```
if (this.backgroundStatus == 'granted') {
            await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(taskName, {
                accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,              
                timeInterval: backgroundTaskTimeIntervall.executeTask, 
                activityType: Location.ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation, //AutomotiveNavigation,
                showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
                foregroundService: {
                    notificationTitle: "App is running",
                    notificationBody: "Location tracking",
                },
            });
        }
```

I have already built the app and tried to activate the notification in the settings. However, this is not possible as it always deactivates it again automatically.